# How to apply integration by parts to a table of values and a function?

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^3 f(x)g'(x)dx= ? $$
Given that
$$ f(x) = x^2 $$
and
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x& 0 & 0.5 & 1 & 1.5 & 2 & 2.5 & 3 \\ \hline
 g(x)&1.5 &1.9 & 2.5 & 2.6 & 3.1 & 3.2 & 4\\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: When you apply integration by parts to the integral, without worrying about the definitions of $f$ and $g$, what do you get?

Comment: There is no unique answer since we can have infinitely many interpolations for $g(x)$

Comment: Do you want the exact value of the integral or a numerical approximation?

Comment: @AbhishekVangipuram I am looking for a left or right Riemann sum estimation.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz I am looking for a left or right Riemann sum estimation.

Comment: @EricTowers I get f(x)g(x) - f'(x)*(integral of g(x))+f''(x)*(integral of integral of g(x)). I stop at f''(x) as f'''(x) = 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using integration by parts, the integral becomes x^2*g(x) from 0 to 3 + the integral of -xg(x)dx.
So we get 36 - integral from 0 to 3 of xg(x) dx. We can use several ways of numerical approximation given the table to approximate this integral now.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{3} &\; f(x) g'(x) \,\mathrm{d}x  \\
    &= \left. f(x)g(x) \right|_{0}^{3} - \int_0^3 \; f'(x) g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x  &  \hspace{-0.5in}\begin{bmatrix} u = f  & \mathrm{d}v = g'\,\mathrm{d}x  \\ \mathrm{d}u = f' \,\mathrm{d}x & v = g \end{bmatrix}  \\
    &= (3^2g(3) - 0^2g(0)) - \int_0^3 \; 2x g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x  \\
    &= 36 - 2 \int_0^3 \; x g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Let $\Delta x = 0.5$.  Then a left Riemann sum for $\int_0^3 \; x g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$ is 
$$  \sum_{i=0}^{5} (0+i\Delta x) g(0 + i\Delta x) (0.5)  $$
and a right Riemann sum for this integral is
$$  \sum_{i=1}^{6} (0+i\Delta x) g(0 + i\Delta x) (0.5)  \text{.}  $$
If you have trouble evaluating either sum (which we can complete because we have enough information about $g$ to do so), leave a comment.